# Delay inline script to load after jquery in MVC

Tags: jquery, delay, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a question regarding the delaying the loading of sciprts.

So basically just to tell you my situation:

I have a page, at the end of the page i load jquery and some other scripts, so that all the html is loaded first and only then the scripts will start loading.

BUT in some places on my pages I'm obliged to write some inline scripts which need to use jquery stuff like $ ... if it is not found i get an error.

I cannot place that inline script in seperat js file and load it at the end because in mvc i cannot then approach model stuff and call action from controller.

So is there a way to say something like load after jquery?

Comment: Are you wrapping your calls inside the jquery ready function?  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: but if i do $(document).ready(function (), ill get an error becuase $ this is not known :(

Comment: @JaceRhea but he hasn't yet loaded jquery..

Comment: i dont know if it is even possible :/ couldn't find anything ...

Comment: load jquery at the top  instead of at the bottom ?

Comment: So why not load jQuery from HEAD section. You shouldn't notice any difference because anyway it will be cached

Comment: yeah maybe that is also the option, i prefered to load everything at the end but yeah ...

Answer (score 0):

Just assign a method on the window.onload event of your html page at the bottom most part of your javascript file.

```
 window.onload = function ()
 {
    do your jQuery thingies here.
 }
```

window.onload event fires after all page resources including external css and js files have been downloaded by the browser.

UPDATE: Please put all your inline scripts at the bottom of your html5 page for this is a good practice. Also, putting all your javascript files on a separate JS file will give you advantages like minification of javascript and caching of external js file to the browser which results on a faster load time.

Comment: the OP mentions multiple inline scripts are used.. this way each would overwrite the previous..

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution for situations where loading jQuery in the head is not desirable or possible.

It involves declaring a temporary `$` function in the head that collects any functions occurring inline using *jQuery-esque* syntax.

The real jQuery then loads and overwrites `window.$` but leaves behind an array of functions stored in `var inlines` which can then be dealt with once jQuery is available.

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <script>

        var inlines = [];

        window.$ = function(inline) {
            inlines.push(inline);
        };

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        ...


        <script>

            $(function() {
                // Do some jQuery stuff.
            }

        </script>

            ...
        <script... load jQuery here!! ></script>
        <script>
            for(var i = 0; i < inlines.length; i++) {
                inlines[i]();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've also applied this kind of approach successfully to inlining require.js require calls before dependencies are known to be loaded.